# Condtional statement to rbind if object exists

Tags: r

I want to `rbind` and object called `old_dat` to main data object called `dat` only if it exists, otherwise `dat` remains unchanged.

`old_dat` is created using a separate function.

I have tried the following two methods:

```
 dat<- ifelse(exists("old_dat", envir = .GlobalEnv),
              rbind(dat,old_dat),dat)
```

and

```
exists("old_dat") && dat<- rbind(dat,old_dat)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
dat <- rbind(dat, if(exists("old_dat")) old_dat)
```